# No visible interface for 'ToDoListTableViewController' declares the selector 'configureCell: atIndexPath:'

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, xcode6

I have created a class 'ToDoListTableViewController' with superclass 'UITableViewController' and have tried implementing this piece of code

```
[self configureCell:((ToDoTableViewCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]) atIndexPath:indexPath];
```

but I am getting the error that is in the title of this question. This is the full method in which it is in

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {
    switch (type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
        {
            [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
        }
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
        {
            [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
        }
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
        {
            [self configureCell:((ToDoTableViewCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]) atIndexPath:indexPath];
            break;
        }
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
        {
            [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the beginning of the implementation file

```
#import "ToDoListTableViewController.h"
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
#import "ToDoTableViewCell.h"

@interface ToDoListTableViewController ()<NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;

@end

@implementation ToDoListTableViewController
```

in code I have found online this method is supposed to work but I am getting this error, can someone help me please?

Comment: You have to create the method `configureCell:atIndexPath:` before using it!

Comment: ahhh ok! I'm following a tutorial and didn't realise why I was getting an error but didn't realise they created the method later on.. thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create the method `configureCell:atIndexPath:` before using it!. If you are following an online tutorial maybe you forgot to create it. Usually people create this method to isolate the setting of the cell properties from the rest of the creation of the cell itself. For example for the case when you try to calculate the height of the cell based on its contents using autolayout.